# javascript cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I'm writing a terrain generator with some unique properties but I've been struggling with a scope issue. This may seem like a noob issue but I've searched the archives and I haven't found anything that illuminates the problem for me. I have a function within a function (I'm not familiar with this object paradigm) and I'm trying to access an inside function from another object. In the code I get an error in Chrome console that says  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined waxy.js:45 BoundingBox waxy.js:45 (anonymous function)" The error occurs at the last line when calling 'bounds.width' I need to expose this function but how?

Here is relevant code:

```
//A wrapper class for an int triple
var Point = (function(dimensions) {
  var x = function() {return dimensions.x || 0}
  var y = function() {return dimensions.y || 0}
  var z = function() {return dimensions.z || 0}
})//end Point

//a working set, rectangular prism
var BoundingBox = (function(dimensions) {
  var lowerBound = function(){return Point(dimensions[0])}
  var upperBound = function(){return Point({x:dimensions[1].x + dimensions[0].x, y:dimensions[1].y + dimensions[0].y, z:dimensions[1].z + dimensions[0].z})}

  var width = function() {return this.upperBound.x - this.lowerBound.x}
  var depth = function() {return this.upperBound.y - this.lowerBound.y}
  var height = function() {return this.upperBound.z - this.lowerBound.z}

  var contains = function(cOffset, cDims) {
    return !((cOffset.x < this.lowerBound.x || cOffset.y < this.lowerBound.y || cOffset.z < this.lowerBound.z) ||
      (cDims.x > this.upperBound.x || cDims.y > this.upperBound.y || cDims.z > this.upperBound.z))
  }
  var intersects = function(iOffset, iDims) {
    return ((iOffset.x >= this.lowerBound.x && iOffset.y >= this.lowerBound.y && iOffset.z >= this.lowerBound.z) ||
      (iDims.x <= this.upperBound.x && iDims.y <= this.upperBound.y && iDims.z <= this.upperBound.z))
  }
  var iterator = function() { return BoxIterator(this) }

})//end BoundingBox

//stores terrain value for each x,y,z in a working set (BoundingBox)
//each property in a list has a value for each node in working set
var MapData = (function(workingSet, properties) {
  var bounds = workingSet
  var props = properties
  var data = []
  //make sure property name is spelled right
  var map = function(x,y,z,property) {return data[x,y,z,props.indexOf(property)] }
  var terrainMap = function(x,y,z) {return map(x,y,z,'terrain')}
  //!isEmpty equiv. isTerrain
  var isEmpty = function(x,y,z) {return map(x,y,z,'terrain')===0}
  var tempMap = function(x,y,z){return map(x,y,z,'temperature')}

})//end MapData

//create a sheet of terrain drops
var DropSheet = (function(opts) {
  var depth = opts.depth
  var width = opts.width
  var rate = opts.rate
  var generate = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i<depth * width; i++) {
      drop[i] = Math.random() <= rate
    }
    return drop
  }
})//end DropSheet

//simulated annealing
var WaxyGenerator = (function(opts) {
  var initialTemp = opts.initialTemp || 1.0
  var fillPercent = opts.fillPercent || 0.35
  var conductivity = opts.conductivity || 0.04
  var freezing = opts.freezing || 0.1
  var floorTemp = opts.floorTemp || 0.0
  var bounds = opts.bounds || BoundingBox([{x:0,y:0,z:0}, {x:80,y:80,z:80}])
  //each property in propertyList has its own map data
  var propertyList = opts.propertyList || ['terrain', 'temperature']
  var materials = opts.materials || ['grass', 'dirt', 'grass_dirt', 'obsidian', 'whitewool', 'brick']
  //map of data
  var data = MapData(bounds, propertyList)
  //create a drop sheet
  var sheetMaker=DropSheet({width:bounds.width, depth:bounds.depth, rate:fillPercent})
  //some functions...
}
```

Comment: make a trigger to the function so we can run it and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a BoundingBox, you should use the `new` keyword, like `opts.bounds || new BoundingBox([{x:0,y:0,z:0}, {x:80,y:80,z:80}])`. Also, to make an object's properties public instead of private, you need to assign them to `this`, like so:

```
this.width = function() {return this.upperBound.x - this.lowerBound.x}
```

Finally, when using `width`, you need to call it because it is a function; `bounds.width()`. You could make it a variable (if it won't change) like this:

```
this.width = this.upperBound.x - this.lowerBound.x;
```

But obviously if upperBound or lowerBound changes the variable won't change with them.

Comment: There are more issues with your code, but they all stem from the same situation.

Comment: The combination of using `new` and exposing the inside functions with `this` worked. Thanks for the help.